# nft accounting support: is this wiki example wrong?

Tags: nftables

[Official nft wiki page accounting example](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_routing_information) look under 'nexthop'

```
nft add rule filter postrouting meter acct { rt nexthop timeout 600s counter }   
nft add rule ip6 filter postrouting meter acct { rt nexthop timeout 600s counter}
```

I adapted the example to:
*sudo nft 'add rule inet firewalld nat__POSTROUTING_RULES_log meter acct { next hop time 600s counter }'*

Hello,
The wiki link I have cited above fails at the command line pointing at the ***unexpected*** '}'.  Ideas?
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, in cases when you use brackets in commands, you need to escape them e.g. `nft 'add chain nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100; }'`  , so the example is might be wrong indeed

Edit: it looks like the brackets are not need to be escaped, only semicolons.

Edit2: Judging by error message (`Error: cannot determine ip protocol version, use "ip nexthop" or "ip6 nexthop" instead`) it seems to me, that  in case of inet table, you must specify ip or ipv6 proto either in action or in the match block:

`nft 'add rule inet firewalld nat__POSTROUTING_RULES_log meter acct {rt ip nexthop timeout 600s counter}`

or in the match block

`nft 'add rule inet firewalld nat__POSTROUTING_RULES_log ip saddr 192.168.2.0/24 meter acct {rt nexthop timeout 600s counter}'`

Comment: Oh I tried that. . I have gone thru numerous permutations of what was between the {} and how semicolons are escaped or not. But it seems that the ***timeout*** vs ***counter*** were never thought thru separating withs spaces or commas or semi-colns are pointed to with errors. This seems to be a pattern.

Comment: Thats strange. I was able to successfully execute lower command without changes. 

The first one gave me an error: "Error: cannot determine ip protocol version, use "ip nexthop" or "ip6 nexthop" instead",  
So I had to specify ip family: `nft 'add rule ip filter postrouting meter acct { rt nexthop timeout 600s counter }'` and it worked: 
`table ip filter {
        chain postrouting {
                meter acct size 65535 { rt ip nexthop timeout 10m counter }
        }
`


My nftables version is v0.9.3 (Topsy), and the shell is bash.

Comment: Look at my added italicized example. Semicolons ,escaped or not, after and before 'counter' and 'nexthop' .none made a difference. The ' ip  nexthop'  are all 'unexpected string'.

Comment: Im not sure if nexthop can be used within inet family. The only mentions about nexthop statements I was able to find are [for ip and ip6 families](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Data_types). If you can use ip family instead of inet, this will work:  `sudo nft 'add rule ip firewalld nat__POSTROUTING_RULES_log meter acct {rt nexthop timeout 600s counter}'`

Comment: Inet is supposed to cover ipv4 AND ipv6. I tried what you suggested and it finally worked. I know 'nexthop' are handled very differently in ipv6 ( extension header , neighbor discovery and router advertisement packets). I am a ccna so what is your experience with nft?

Comment: Yes, Inet is supposed to be IPv4+IPv6. I was confused a bit, cause in the original post you haven't specified family for the first command, and explicitly specified v6 for the second one. You may use the rule inside of inet family table, but for the nexthop action you will need to somehow specify if its ip or ipv6 anyway, either in match block (ip saddr,ip6 daddr) or in the action block, so you end up splitting them anyway. 
`Error: cannot determine ip protocol version, use "ip nexthop" or "ip6 nexthop" instead`

Comment: `sudo nft 'add rule inet firewalld nat__POSTROUTING_RULES_log meter acct {rt ip nexthop timeout 600s counter}'` or `nft 'add rule inet firewalld nat__POSTROUTING_RULES_log ip saddr 192.168.2.0/24 meter acct {rt nexthop timeout 600s counter}'` or  `nft 'add rule inet firewalld nat__POSTROUTING_RULES_log meter acct {rt ip6 nexthop timeout 600s counter}'` are all valid commands. I'm graduated with System & Network Administration this June.  Can't qualify @ Cisco due to sanctions. I've never used inet or v6 families of nftables, as we don't use v6 in prod, and our ISP doesn't offer v6 either.

Comment: IPv6 is a very nice thing. But until it's fully implemented everywhere, it creates more problems that it solves.

Comment: Indeed. 

I'd rather not to use IPv6, if it means to use NAT64, NAT46, teredo + IPv4 for it to work. It also forces you to create 2+ times more firewall rules, while also making troubleshooting harder. 

Not to mention that many libraries still dont fully support v6 (like PcapPlusPlus), as well as some implementations of dynamic routing in Home/SOHO routers.